# Pass variable in vimscript function to split

Tags: vimscript

I am trying to create a command which compares the current file with another by calling `:DiffWith(foo.rb)`. See the following code:

```
function DiffWith(file)
  botright vsplit a:file
  windo diffthis
endfunction
command -nargs=1 -complete=file Diffwith call DiffWith(<f-args>)
```

However, it opens a new file named `a:file` instead of the file I state. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Would this work `:botright vertical diffpsplit foo.rb`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many commands in Vim, including `:botright` and `:vsplit`, expect plain text, no variables or expressions ( see [`:help 41.3`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#41%2e3) and [`:help expression`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expression) to know what a expression means). But there are commands that do expect variables and/or expressions, such as `:echo` and `:execute`.

[String interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) is common in many programming languages such as Groovy, Kotlin, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, Scala, and Swift, and most Unix shells, but not Vimscript. However, when a Vim command expects an expression, it can evaluate variables and use the concatenation operator (the dot `.`) to obtain the same effect.

So it would be great if we could use the content of a variable, rather than just plain text, to issue commands such as `:botright vsplit a:file`. For that purpose, Vim gives us the `:execute` command, from  [`:help :execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3aexecute):

```
:exe[cute] {expr1} ..    Executes the string that results from the
                         evaluation of {expr1} as an Ex command.  Multiple
                         arguments are concatenated, with a space in
                         between.  To avoid the extra space use the "."
                         operator to concatenate strings into one 
                         argument.
```

In that way, you can take advantage of the `:execute` command  to get the intended result, as follows:

```
function DiffWith(file)
  execute "botright vsplit" a:file
  windo diffthis
endfunction
command -nargs=1 -complete=file Diffwith call DiffWith(<f-args>)
```

and then you can call it by typing in:

```
:Diffwith foo.rb
```

### Bonus

As Peter Rincker pointed out, Vim includes a similar functionality, see below:

```
:botright vertical diffsplit foo.rb
```

and you can rewrite your command in this way:

```
:command! -nargs=1 -complete=file Diffwith botright vertical diffsplit <args>
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I don't understand why vim is handling both things different. I would have expected that `botright vsplit "a:file"` would be the form to open a file named “a:file”, witthout quotes should it be a variable…

Comment: @Ben Please read the new content, does it help?

Comment: @Ben because this would traditionally try to edit a file `"a:file"` and since this is a valid name, it would not be possible to edit such a file. So this would have broken backwards compatibility when vimscript was added so it was decided against it, and only a very limited number of commands added, that expect expressions instead of literals. Therefore you have to use `exe`